# laravel can not get image's extension

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am using Laravel `5.3`,
I crop an image via javascript on the front end and upload it to back end via ajax,

The headers is like this:
[image]

And `dd()` the image:

```
public function changeAvatar(Request $request)
{

    $file = $request->file('croppedImage');
    dd($file);

}
```

The result is like this:
[image]

But,dd() the extension of the image:

```
public function changeAvatar(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('croppedImage');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    dd($extension);
}
```

The result is `''`.

Why is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$file->clientExtension()` ? https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html#method_clientExtension

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading a "blob" filename without the extension whatsoever, so you have to use [mimeType](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_mimeType) or [type](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_type) to assign a proper extension.